# How to Combine Multiple Return Functions (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am learning JavaScript so that I can implement Google Tag Manager.  I have a list of paths that I would like GTM to rewrite to something friendlier like so:

```
function() {
      return document.location.pathname.indexOf('/l/138281/2016-06-07/dy383') > -1 ? 'Test Success' : undefined;
    }

function() {
      return document.location.pathname.indexOf('/l/138281/2016-04-03/55z63') > -1 ? 'SPP Contact Success' : undefined;
```

I'm just not sure how to combine these returns into one function (I currently have about 30 URLs to rewrite).  I imagine I can use if/else, but advice would be quite lovely.

--edit--

```
URL Path        Rewrite To
/test-638-jsj   /test-success
/spp-zxcv-765   /spp-contact-success
/foo-asdf-123   /foo
/foo-bar-987    /foo-bar
```

The return function mentioned above does this beautifully for an individual link.  I just want to be able to rewrite a series of URLs in one function (or however it makes sense to do this most specifically).  Hopefully that helps clarify.

Thanks!

Comment: You want to return a suitable data structure, such as an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) or an [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

Comment: Please describe the actual problem you're trying to solve.  Then, show a set of input and a desired output so we can create efficient code to produce that output, given the input.

Answer (score 0):

It is always a great idea to structure your code: separate abstract functionality from the specific problem.

What you are actually doing is scannins strings for occurences of keywords and returning specific values if such a keyword has been found.

Therefore, you need a function performing the above computation and a JavaScript datastructure holding your keywords and their values (= Object):

```js
// Return patterns[key] if any key is found in string, else return string:
function match(string, patterns) {
  for (key of Object.keys(patterns)) {
    if (string.indexOf(key) > -1) return patterns[key];
  }
  return string;
}

var patterns = {
  '/l/138281/2016-06-07/dy383': 'Test Success',
  '/l/138281/2016-04-03/55z63': 'SPP Contact Success'
}

console.log(match('/l/138281/2016-06-07/dy383', patterns)); // "Test Success"
console.log(match('/doesnotexist', patterns)); // "/doesnotexist"
console.log(match(document.location.pathname, patterns));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help - much appreciated!  I modified this to work with Google Tag Manager using a custom JS variable, which did not work.  I wound up using a couple of lookup tables to do the work of rewriting paths and titles for the series of pages.